# Angular Animations and Dynamically updating values

Tags: angular, css-animations, angular-animations

I am trying to create a quiz and I would like to display one question at a time. I would like to animate between each of the questions.

My approach is to loop through a json object of questions and display them in a column. I created an angular animation where I set the transformY, but for this to be dynamic I need to find a way to set this value dynamically.

HTML Code below:

```
<div [@slide]="isUp ? 'up' : 'down'" *ngFor="let question of questions">
    <h2>{{ question.question }}</h2>
</div>
```

Animation in component

```
animations: [
   trigger('slide', [
      state('up', style({
         opacity: 1,
         transform: 'translateY(dynamicallySetValue)', 
    })),
   state('down', style({
      opacity: 0,
      transform: 'translateY(dynamicallySetValue)',
   })),
   transition('up => down', [
    animate('0.5s ease-in')
   ]),
   transition('down => up', [
    animate('0.5s ease-in')
   ]),
 ]),
],
```

Is there a way to set the translateY() to a dynamic value that changes based on the div height?

Answer (score 0):

After being in a weeds for a while I came up with the followiing solution for anyone else that might be interested in doing something similar.

My approach was to change the from and to states.

```
 <div [@scrollAnimation]="isUp? fromState:toState" 
 (@scrollAnimation.done)="onAnimationEvent($event)" *ngFor="let question of 
 questions, let i = index">
    <h2>{{i+1}}. {{ question.question }}</h2>
 </div>
```

Then I dynamically update question index when clicking either clicking previous or next calling the toggle() function.

```
toggle(direction) {
   this.isUp = true;
   this.direction = direction;
   if(direction == 'up')
   {
     this.toState = "normal";
     this.fromState = "down";
     if(this.activeQuestion < this.questions.length-1)
       this.activeQuestion++;
   }
   if(direction == 'down')
   {
     this.toState = "normal";
     this.fromState = "up";
     if(this.activeQuestion > 0)
        this.activeQuestion--;
   }
 }
```

I then set the variable isUp to true which will call the animation and on done it will call the onAnimationEvent() function which updates the states.

```
 onAnimationEvent ( event:AnimationEvent ) {
    if(this.direction == "up")
    {
       this.fromState = "down";
       this.toState ="normal"; 
    }
    if(this.direction == "down")
   {
      this.fromState = "up";
      this.toState ="normal";
   }

   this.isUp = false;
   this.show();
 }
```

Then isUp is set back to false which plays the next animation. I have also included my animation code below.

```
 trigger('scrollAnimation', [
  state('up', style({transform: 'translateY(-20%)',opacity:0, offset: 0})),
  state('normal', style({transform: 'translateY(20%)',opacity:1, offset: 0})),
  state('down', style({transform: 'translateY(60%)',opacity:0, offset: 0})),

  transition('normal => up', [
    animate('0.5s ease')
  ]),
  transition('normal => down', [
    animate('0.5s ease')
  ]),
  transition('up => normal', [
    animate('2s ease', keyframes([
      style({ transform: 'translateY(80%)',opacity:0, offset: 0.05 }),
      style({ transform: 'translateY(20%)',opacity:1, offset: 0.55 }),

    ])),
  ]),
  transition('down => normal', [
    animate('2s ease', keyframes([
      style({ transform: 'translateY(-20%)',opacity:0, offset: 0.05}),
      style({ transform: 'translateY(20%)',opacity:1, offset: 0.55 }),
    ]))
  ]),
]),
```

I hope this helps.